# Use only one Coupon Code among a set

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon

Magento 1.9
We want to Create a group of different coupon codes , and there is chance that multiple coupon code can be received by single customer. Here system must restrict to use only one coupon code in that group. If customer uses coupon from another group then it can allow. Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Magento's out-of-the box Shopping cart price rule can do this. Under the Rule Information tab, use the field **Uses per customer**. Here you can set the limit to 1.

> Note that this limit is applicable only for logged in users.

You can enter the group of Coupon codes in the same rule itself. For this purpose, under **Rule Information** tab, set **Coupon** to **Specific Coupon** and a new field will be introduced just below, called **Coupon Code**. In this field you can enter Coupon codes yourself or you can ask the system to generate the coupon codes for you by ticking the checkbox **Use Auto Generation**.